# JW Player Resizing issue in chrome

Tags: google-chrome, video, resize, html5-video, jwplayer

I am having a weird problem with my video resizing incorrectly in chrome.

I have tried many different suggestions I've found on google but none seem to work. The video is 16:9 and I used a aspect ratio calculator to pick a scaled size for the video. It works fine in firefox, opera etc....but as you will see chrome resizes it incorrectly.

The site can be viewed at www.conchandmedia.com

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated

Comment: One thing you can try is to mess with the player's "stretching" variable. I would try to see if using "exactfit" helps.

Comment: I actually have tried this but no luck ....I am not still stuck on this :(

Comment: Maybe try a different stretching option?